# Random bounded triangular $T_n$ s.t. $Var[T_nS_nT_n^\top]\to 0$ for nonrandom psd $S_n$. Does $(T_n-\bar T_n)S_n\to^P0$ for some nonradom $\bar T_n$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, positive-semidefinite, random-matrices, cholesky-decomposition

Let $T_n$ be a sequence of square random matrices with $T_n$ lower triangular with $diag(T_n)=(1,1...,1)$ and $S_n$ a sequence of deterministic symmetric psd matrices. All matrices are in $R^{d\times d}$ where $d$ is fixed. Assume
$$E[\|T_nS_nT_n^\top-E[T_nS_nT_n^\top]\|_F^2]\le 1/n.$$
and further assume that, with probability one, $\|T_n\|\le 1, \|S_n\|\le 1$ in operator norm.
Is it always true that there exists a deterministic $\bar T_n$ lower triangular such that
$$
(T_n-\bar T_n)S_n \to^P 0
$$
where $\to^P$ indicates convergence in probability?

---

##### Partial answer:

Since all matrices are bounded, by extracting a subsequence if necessary, we may assume that $E[T_nS_nT_n^\top]$ converges to some psd matrix, say $A$.
The situation is significantly easier if $A$ is positive definite. Then if $L_n L_n^\top$ is the Cholesky decompoistion of $S_n$, by continuity of the Cholesky factor and the continuous mapping theorem, we have
$T_nL_n \to^P \text{Chol}(A)$. We may then set $\bar T_n = \text{Chol}(A)L_n^{-1}$ and since $\|L_n\|_{op}^2=\|S_n\|_{op}\le 1$,
$$
(T_n-\bar T_n)S_n = (T_n L_n - \text{Chol}(A))L_n^\top
\to^P 0.
$$
The more tricky issue is when $A$ is not invertible.